# На каких серверах находится пользователь

Tags: python, discord

Я хотел узнать, как узнать на каких серверах пользователь находится (disnake)? Вот пример (как мне казалось, но такого нет)

```
@bot.command()
async def tet(ctx):
    for guil in bot.guilds:
        for member in guil.members:
            for guild in member.guilds:
                print(guild)
```

С ошибкой:

```
25920000
Бот готов к работе
Ignoring exception in command tet:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 173, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 657, in tet
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'guilds'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/bot_base.py", line 591, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 914, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 182, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'guilds'
```

Comment: `discord.Member` — это участник только одного конкретного сервера. Поэтому все информацию о нем вы можете получить только в рамках того сервера, на котором этот участник находится. Посмотреть все сервера, на которых состоит данный участник нельзя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете узнать на каких серверах находится пользователь.

Возможно узнать только сервера на которых находится бот и пользователь.

Для этого создаём переменную в которую будут внесены данные:

```
    test = ""
```

Затем перебираем список гильдий бота:

```
    for guild in bot.guilds:
```

Далее если этот пользователь находится на сервере где есть бот..

```
        if ctx.author in guild.members:
```

Он записывает его в переменную:

```
            if test == "":
                test = f"{guild}"
            else:
                test = f"{test}, {guild}"
```

Отправляем сообщение с результатом и радуемся.

```
    await ctx.send(test)
```

Полный код:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    test = ""
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        if ctx.author in guild.members:
            if test == "":
                test = f"{guild}"
            else:
                test = f"{test}, {guild}"
    await ctx.send(test)
```

Comment: ___Если я Вам помог, отметьте этот ответ галочкой и полезным.___